# executing jquery code after ajax is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm having an ajax call that prints some links in the page. Than I want to click on any 1 of these links to do something like alert but it's not working

here's the document.ready code

```
setTimeout(getFur(),500);

$("#curFur a").on("click",function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

and the getFur function (php variables work without any problem because there's some php queries and the there's no problem with the ajax)

```
var ajax = false;
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var qst = "?roomid=<?=$roomID?>&lang=<?=$lang?>";
ajax.open("POST","ajax/curfur.php"+qst);
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
        $("#curFur").html(ajax.responseText);
    }
}
ajax.send(null);
```

the problem now is clicking the links do nothing at all i've even tried to remove these links but didn't work

```
$("#curFur a").remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your anchors has been added to the DOM dynamically by an AJAX call, you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach events such as `click` in your case to these newly added anchors:

```
$('#curFur').on("click",'a',function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

getFur() it executes immediately

```
setTimeout(getFur(),500);
```

Change to this

```
setTimeout(getFur,500);
```

or

```
   setTimeout(function() {
       getFur();

  },500);
```